# How to set cookie to md5 of UNIQUE_ID in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, uniqueidentifier

I'm currently creating unique visit_id cookie in Apache with following code:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_COOKIE}" "(^|;)\s*visit_id\s*=([A-Za-z0-9@-]+)" [NC]
RewriteRule ".?" - [CO=visit_id:%2:.www.mydomain.com:30,S=1]
RewriteRule ".?" - [CO=visit_id:%{ENV:UNIQUE_ID}:.www.mydomain.com:30]
```

(If cookie exists, refresh its expiration, else create cookie with value of UNIQUE_ID environment variable from mod_unique_id.)

This is working, but I would like to use more random-looking id, for example md5 of UNIQUE_ID. Is there a way to do this with just Apache configuration?

I tried `%{md5:%{ENV:UNIQUE_ID}}` but that doesn't work.

Comment: You should use `session` support from the language you are using behind apache. Do you use php, python, ruby?

Comment: I want this cookie set also for files served directly with Apache, so I can't use php etc.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is the main problem?

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici I want to identify all access-log entries belonging to same "visit". While it's not a huge deal if someone tries to spoof UNIQUE_ID (which is quite easy), I would prefer ID to be something harder to spoof.